# Button within multiple divs wont change with css

Tags: php, html, css

The button with in my code will not change at all, i have tried listing all the divs and this still has not worked

This is the code for the page, php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- edit the refrence to show them the different options -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IndexopOr.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styler.php">-->
    <title>Wccs Canteen</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="Top_Text">WCCS Lunch Order</h1>
<div id="Menu-fixer1">
<div id="Menu_fin1">

<img src="WCCS Logo.png" id="lighthouse">

</div>
</div>

<div id="Menu-fixer">
<div id="Menu_fin">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- this will change when the css source is changed between Indexop1 and Indexop2, currently it is linked to Index, the file i will change when we have decided what we like -->
            <a href="#" id="Linker"><span>Menu </span></a>      
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>

            <a href="#" id="Linker"><span>Order </span></a>     
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>

            <a href="#" id="Linker" class="Contact_us_link"><span>Contact Us </span></a>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

<div id="menu_bar">
<div id="menu_user">
<style type="text/css">
    #menu_user {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        bottom:20%;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: white;
        font-family: HelvLight, verdana;

    }
</style>
<?php
            //seeing as you like documentation sir i added this in telling you about sessions, remind me to tell you if you want it explained
            if (isset($_SESSION['food'])) {
                echo 'Student: '.$_SESSION['food'];
                echo $_SESSION['ln'];


            } else {
                echo "You are not logged in!";
            }

            ?>

            </div>
    <div id="menubar_bottom">
    <h1 class="menu_Hpg">Menu</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div id="list_space">
    <div id="Right_list">

        </div>
    <div id="Left_orders">
    <button id="but">Confirm</button>
    </div>

    <!--<div id="Bar"></div>-->
    <div id="mid_bar"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the css code:

```
#but button {
color:blue;
}
```

there is alot of css that is the part editing the button, please tell me why it doesn't work. It works when i just type style next to it and add it but it doesn't allow me to put a hover option on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#but button` means that you are looking for button inside element with id but. You do not have such situation in your code. You have button with id but so it must be like this:

```
button#but
```

Comment: Why not just use `#but`?  It would be a more efficient selector

Comment: It can be #but there, but I just wanted fully explain difference between `#but button` and `button#but`

Answer (score 0):

change '#but button' to 'button#but' in your css, because button has the id not its parent element

```
button#but {
color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this selector, it select button that having attribute id=but

**button#but**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple buttons, you must use classes and not id's. The id's can be used only one per page.
in any case, the syntax is correct **button#but{}** or **#but{}**.